# Appending to a jsonb array in postgres using jsonb_insert

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with a jsonb column to which I want to append a new record.

This is the content of my table's data column.

```
data =    [
    { "id" : "1",
      "content" : "cat"},
    { "id" : "2",
      "content" : "rat"},
    { "id" : "3",
      "content" : "dog"},
       ...
       ...

    { "id" : "n",
      "content" : "hamster"}
    ]
```

I want to add

```
{ "id" : "n+1",
          "content" : "goat"}
```

to data. I know I can use the concatenate operator `||` to do this. However, I want to understand if I can use the `jsonb_insert` to do this as well?
can I also use `jsonb_insert` to

1. insert the new records any where arbitrarily
2. insert the new record at the start of the jsonb array
3. append the new record to the jsonb
   array at the end

extra question;
if I want to turn the content of id 3, from dog to cow, should I do;

```
SELECT jsonb_set(data, '{id, 4}', '{"content":"cow"}'::jsonb) FROM tablename;
```